# 2 different input value in 1 line

Tags: c++

Can anyone help me on how can I do or get the 2 input that accepts 2 different value at the same time.

The red square in the picture **M2** is the INPUT I enter, then if I input **M1** it will lead to Milk that costs 10.50.

[Here is the example input.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yob0B.png)

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code generation service. Post a [mcve] and a specific question about what's not working.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you are trying to take an input and output one line or another. You can do this very easily by just using an if statement.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string INPUT;
    cout << "The beginning of your code (the table, information, selection, and 'item selected:')";
    cin >> INPUT;
    if (INPUT == "possible inputs") {
        cout << "Cash amount:" << price;
    }
}
```